# Webcam library for C on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, webcam

Is there any c library to get a video from the webcam on linux?

Comment: Can you please tell what library you ended up using?

Answer (score 14):

A lot of us use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) (cross-platform Computer Vision library, currently on v2.1)

The following snippet grabs frames from camera, converts them to grayscale and displays them on the screen:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"


typedef IplImage* (*callback_prototype)(IplImage*);


/* 
 * make_it_gray: custom callback to convert a colored frame to its grayscale version.
 * Remember that you must deallocate the returned IplImage* yourself after calling this function.
 */
IplImage* make_it_gray(IplImage* frame)
{
    // Allocate space for a new image
    IplImage* gray_frame = 0;
    gray_frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width, frame->height), frame->depth, 1);
    if (!gray_frame)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "!!! cvCreateImage failed!\n" );
      return NULL;
    }

    cvCvtColor(frame, gray_frame, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    return gray_frame; 
}

/*
 * process_video: retrieves frames from camera and executes a callback to do individual frame processing.
 * Keep in mind that if your callback takes too much time to execute, you might loose a few frames from 
 * the camera.
 */
void process_video(callback_prototype custom_cb)
{           
    // Initialize camera
    CvCapture *capture = 0;
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
    if (!capture) 
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "!!! Cannot open initialize webcam!\n" );
      return;
    }

    // Create a window for the video 
    cvNamedWindow("result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    IplImage* frame = 0;
    char key = 0;
    while (key != 27) // ESC
    {    
      frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
      if(!frame) 
      {
          fprintf( stderr, "!!! cvQueryFrame failed!\n" );
          break;
      }

      // Execute callback on each frame
      IplImage* processed_frame = (*custom_cb)(frame);

      // Display processed frame
      cvShowImage("result", processed_frame);

      // Release resources
      cvReleaseImage(&processed_frame);

      // Exit when user press ESC
      key = cvWaitKey(10);
    }

    // Free memory
    cvDestroyWindow("result");
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    process_video(make_it_gray);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: New link http://opencv.org/

Comment: Hint on how to compile the code snippet above on OpenCV 3.4.1 using gcc:
gcc abovecode.c -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio

Answer (score 9):

**`v4l2` official examples**

What you get:

- `./v4l2grab`: capture a few snapshots to files `outNNN.ppm`
- `./v4l2gl`: show video live on a window using an OpenGL texture (immediate rendering, hey!) and raw X11 windowing (plus GLUT's `gluLookAt` for good measure).

How to get it on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep libv4l-dev
git clone git://linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git
cd v4l-utils
# Matching the installed version of dpkg -s libv4l-dev
git checkout v4l-utils-1.10.0
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
# TODO: fails halfway, but it does not matter for us now.
cd contrib/tests
make
```

It is also easy to use those examples outside of the Git tree, just copy them out, make relative includes `""` absolute `<>`, and remove `config.h`. I've done that for you at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/09fe73d248f7da2e9c9f3eff2520a143c259f4a6/v4l2

**Minimal example from docs**

The docs 4.9.0 contain what appears to be a minimal version of `./v4l2grab` at https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-new/uapi/v4l/v4l2grab-example.html. I needed to patch it minimally and I've sent the patch to http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-media/ (their docs live in the Linux kernel tree as rst, neat), where it was dully ignored.

Usage:

```
gcc v4l2grab.c -lv4l2
./a.out
```

Patched code:

```
/* V4L2 video picture grabber
Copyright (C) 2009 Mauro Carvalho Chehab <mchehab@infradead.org>

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation version 2 of the License.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <libv4l2.h>

#define CLEAR(x) memset(&(x), 0, sizeof(x))

struct buffer {
        void   *start;
        size_t length;
};

static void xioctl(int fh, int request, void *arg)
{
        int r;

        do {
                r = v4l2_ioctl(fh, request, arg);
        } while (r == -1 && ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN)));

        if (r == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error %d, %s\\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct v4l2_format              fmt;
        struct v4l2_buffer              buf;
        struct v4l2_requestbuffers      req;
        enum v4l2_buf_type              type;
        fd_set                          fds;
        struct timeval                  tv;
        int                             r, fd = -1;
        unsigned int                    i, n_buffers;
        char                            *dev_name = "/dev/video0";
        char                            out_name[256];
        FILE                            *fout;
        struct buffer                   *buffers;

        fd = v4l2_open(dev_name, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
        if (fd < 0) {
                perror("Cannot open device");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        CLEAR(fmt);
        fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        fmt.fmt.pix.width       = 640;
        fmt.fmt.pix.height      = 480;
        fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
        fmt.fmt.pix.field       = V4L2_FIELD_INTERLACED;
        xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt);
        if (fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat != V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24) {
                printf("Libv4l didn't accept RGB24 format. Can't proceed.\\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ((fmt.fmt.pix.width != 640) || (fmt.fmt.pix.height != 480))
                printf("Warning: driver is sending image at %dx%d\\n",
                        fmt.fmt.pix.width, fmt.fmt.pix.height);

        CLEAR(req);
        req.count = 2;
        req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req);

        buffers = calloc(req.count, sizeof(*buffers));
        for (n_buffers = 0; n_buffers < req.count; ++n_buffers) {
                CLEAR(buf);

                buf.type        = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory      = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                buf.index       = n_buffers;

                xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buf);

                buffers[n_buffers].length = buf.length;
                buffers[n_buffers].start = v4l2_mmap(NULL, buf.length,
                            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                            fd, buf.m.offset);

                if (MAP_FAILED == buffers[n_buffers].start) {
                        perror("mmap");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i) {
                CLEAR(buf);
                buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                buf.index = i;
                xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf);
        }
        type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;

        xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type);
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                do {
                        FD_ZERO(&fds);
                        FD_SET(fd, &fds);

                        /* Timeout. */
                        tv.tv_sec = 2;
                        tv.tv_usec = 0;

                        r = select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
                } while ((r == -1 && (errno = EINTR)));
                if (r == -1) {
                        perror("select");
                        return errno;
                }

                CLEAR(buf);
                buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf);

                sprintf(out_name, "out%03d.ppm", i);
                fout = fopen(out_name, "w");
                if (!fout) {
                        perror("Cannot open image");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                fprintf(fout, "P6\n%d %d 255\n",
                        fmt.fmt.pix.width, fmt.fmt.pix.height);
                fwrite(buffers[buf.index].start, buf.bytesused, 1, fout);
                fclose(fout);

                xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf);
        }

        type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF, &type);
        for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i)
                v4l2_munmap(buffers[i].start, buffers[i].length);
        v4l2_close(fd);

        return 0;
}
```

**Header only object oriented version for reuse**

Extracted from the example in the docs, but in a form that makes it super easy to reuse.

common_v4l2.h

```
#ifndef COMMON_V4L2_H
#define COMMON_V4L2_H

#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <libv4l2.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>

#define COMMON_V4L2_CLEAR(x) memset(&(x), 0, sizeof(x))

typedef struct {
    void *start;
    size_t length;
} CommonV4l2_Buffer;

typedef struct {
    int fd;
    CommonV4l2_Buffer *buffers;
    struct v4l2_buffer buf;
    unsigned int n_buffers;
} CommonV4l2;

void CommonV4l2_xioctl(int fh, unsigned long int request, void *arg)
{
    int r;
    do {
        r = v4l2_ioctl(fh, request, arg);
    } while (r == -1 && ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN)));
    if (r == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void CommonV4l2_init(CommonV4l2 *this, char *dev_name, unsigned int x_res, unsigned int y_res) {
    enum v4l2_buf_type type;
    struct v4l2_format fmt;
    struct v4l2_requestbuffers req;
    unsigned int i;

    this->fd = v4l2_open(dev_name, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
    if (this->fd < 0) {
        perror("Cannot open device");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    COMMON_V4L2_CLEAR(fmt);
    fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    fmt.fmt.pix.width       = x_res;
    fmt.fmt.pix.height      = y_res;
    fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
    fmt.fmt.pix.field       = V4L2_FIELD_INTERLACED;
    CommonV4l2_xioctl(this->fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt);
    if ((fmt.fmt.pix.width != x_res) || (fmt.fmt.pix.height != y_res))
        printf("Warning: driver is sending image at %dx%d\n",
            fmt.fmt.pix.width, fmt.fmt.pix.height);
    COMMON_V4L2_CLEAR(req);
    req.count = 2;
    req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    CommonV4l2_xioctl(this->fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req);
    this->buffers = calloc(req.count, sizeof(*this->buffers));
    for (this->n_buffers = 0; this->n_buffers < req.count; ++this->n_buffers) {
        COMMON_V4L2_CLEAR(this->buf);
        this->buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        this->buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        this->buf.index = this->n_buffers;
        CommonV4l2_xioctl(this->fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &this->buf);
        this->buffers[this->n_buffers].length = this->buf.length;
        this->buffers[this->n_buffers].start = v4l2_mmap(NULL, this->buf.length,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, this->fd, this->buf.m.offset);
        if (MAP_FAILED == this->buffers[this->n_buffers].start) {
            perror("mmap");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < this->n_buffers; ++i) {
        COMMON_V4L2_CLEAR(this->buf);
        this->buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        this->buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        this->buf.index = i;
        CommonV4l2_xioctl(this->fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &this->buf);
    }
    type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    CommonV4l2_xioctl(this->fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type);
}

void CommonV4l2_update_image(CommonV4l2 *this) {
    fd_set fds;
    int r;
    struct timeval tv;

    do {
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(this->fd, &fds);

        /* Timeout. */
        tv.tv_sec = 2;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        r = select(this->fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    } while ((r == -1 && (errno == EINTR)));
    if (r == -1) {
        perror("select");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    COMMON_V4L2_CLEAR(this->buf);
    this->buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    this->buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    CommonV4l2_xioctl(this->fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &this->buf);
    CommonV4l2_xioctl(this->fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &this->buf);
}

char * CommonV4l2_get_image(CommonV4l2 *this) {
    return ((char *)this->buffers[this->buf.index].start);
}

size_t CommonV4l2_get_image_size(CommonV4l2 *this) {
    return this->buffers[this->buf.index].length;
}

void CommonV4l2_deinit(CommonV4l2 *this) {
    unsigned int i;
    enum v4l2_buf_type type;

    type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    CommonV4l2_xioctl(this->fd, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF, &type);
    for (i = 0; i < this->n_buffers; ++i)
        v4l2_munmap(this->buffers[i].start, this->buffers[i].length);
    v4l2_close(this->fd);
    free(this->buffers);
}

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "common_v4l2.h"

static void save_ppm(
    unsigned int i,
    unsigned int x_res,
    unsigned int y_res,
    size_t data_lenght,
    char *data
) {
    FILE *fout;
    char out_name[256];

    sprintf(out_name, "out%03d.ppm", i);
    fout = fopen(out_name, "w");
    if (!fout) {
        perror("error: fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(fout, "P6\n%d %d 255\n", x_res, y_res);
    fwrite(data, data_lenght, 1, fout);
    fclose(fout);
}

int main(void) {
    CommonV4l2 common_v4l2;
    char *dev_name = "/dev/video0";
    struct buffer *buffers;
    unsigned int
        i,
        x_res = 640,
        y_res = 480
    ;

    CommonV4l2_init(&common_v4l2, dev_name, x_res, y_res);
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        CommonV4l2_update_image(&common_v4l2);
        save_ppm(
            i,
            x_res,
            y_res,
            CommonV4l2_get_image_size(&common_v4l2),
            CommonV4l2_get_image(&common_v4l2)
        );
    }
    CommonV4l2_deinit(&common_v4l2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Upstream: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/be5d6444bddab93e95949b3388d92007b5ca916f/v4l2/common_v4l2.h

**SDL**

Video capture is in their roadmap: https://wiki.libsdl.org/Roadmap and I bet it will wrap v4l on Linux.

It will be sweet when we get that portability layer, with less bloat than OpenCV.

Comment: Awesome! Can I accept that on @joxer's behalf? ;) (PS: everything compiled fine on my 16.04, without any patches, in 2018)

Comment: @Matthieu yes, I accept your accept :-)

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is probably: [video4linux (V4L)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux)

It's easy to use, and powerful.

Comment: Official link is http://www.linuxtv.org/