# Open source portable/cross-platform video camera capture library

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

I like to know if there's a open-source, cross-platform library for capturing web-cam data. Any other suggestions are welcome in case such solutions are not available. I am looking for something similar to [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) if possible but this is not absolutely mandatory.

Also open-source & cross-platform projects falling into this category are a good starting point.

Thanks in advance,

Iulian

**Libraries found:**

[portvideo](http://portvideo.sourceforge.net/). Does anyone have any experience with it?

[reactivision](http://reactivision.sourceforge.net/). This one seems to be pretty cool and well supported.

[libvidcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libvidcap/). Didn't manage to test it under Linux for the moment.

[opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) and its [highgui](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui._high-level_gui_and_media_io.html) project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278112/webcam-library-for-c-on-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a look at [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) and its [highgui](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui._high-level_gui_and_media_io.html) project.

Comment: OpeenCV does it, but feels like overkill :-s

Answer (score 2):

I heard [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) can do that. Never used it myself, so please take this suggestion with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I think PortVideo is discontinued in favour of reactivision. Also here are a few others. I've never used either of them but plan on it soon. I also am looking for a good video capture API. These two also seem to offer processing and audio. I like PortAudio so much though that I'd like to stick with them for audio.

[OpenML](http://www.khronos.org/openml/)

[FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: ffmpeg didn't support windows capturing, at least couple of years ago. I had to implement this myself