# capture video from usb camera in linux with c++

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I was wondering how is it possible to capture a video from a usb camera device connected to my linux machine with c++ and the terminal alone or perhaps a bash script, i see the terminal but i dont think an echo would provide me with video or frames. Help would be extremely appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278112/webcam-library-for-c-on-linux

Comment: gave more specifics. thank you

Comment: OpenCV also has a C++ interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a look at this [page](http://www.twam.info/linux/v4l2grab-grabbing-jpegs-from-v4l2-devices) . The v4l2grab is a program that reads raw images and convert them to jpeg and is run in a terminal

Comment: do i have to install v4l? or does it come automatically with ubuntu?

Comment: v4l2 is part of the kernel. to compile the program, you need to have a compiler and related libraries installed. I don't know what comes pre-installed with ubuntu.

Comment: do you know of a way to stream it to a server? assuming my machine is the client? or to just stream it to another computer? thank you

Comment: the question is too generic. Maybe using ekiga can be enough?

Comment: I mean, it is a voip audio/video phone, I don't know if this is what you want to achieve. It was a solution out-of-the box. If you talk about streaming, you need to choose a protocol. If you want rtsp check http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/ . In that page there was a link to the Elphel video camera sources, you can use them as a reference. But this library is not so easy to learn....