# What is the range of a RAW image in Linux?

Tags: linux, webcam, c99

I want to process a webcam stream. It has to be fast, so I'm using RAW format for images. Following this [How to capture still image from webcam on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378944/how-to-capture-still-image-from-webcam-on-linux?rq=1) I produced a similar program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

const int SIZE=320*240;
int main(){
FILE* camera, *output;
camera=fopen("/dev/video0","rb");
output=fopen("image.raw","wb");
float data[SIZE];
fread(data,sizeof(float),SIZE,camera);
float max=FLT_MAX;
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
data[i]=max-data[i];
}
fwrite(data,sizeof(float),SIZE,output);
fclose(camera); 
fclose(output);
return 0;
}
```

When I omit the line that modify the data (data[i]=max-data[i];) everything works fine, I'm getting an image in raw format that correspond to the webcam stream. But I want to make simple processing like treshold and there, invert the colors of the picture. However, FLT_MAX doesn't seems to be the solution since applying (data[i]=max-data[i]) gives me a garbage image (still readable by an image reading software, but no more by a human eye. See [image: corrupted image]. Thus my question is : what is the range for the float value that describe a RAW picture

EDIT: I tried a bit of thinkering, I have modified the line that process the picure to data[i]=data[SIZE-i]; and got a horizontal mirrored picture so I think the picture format in 1 float per pixel, still dont' know the range.

Comment: I don't know the exact range, but typically raw images are stored with 10,12,14,or 16 bits per pixel. You probably got 12 or 14 bit

Comment: Usually using raw formats makes things slow, not fast. The bottleneck you're running into with video is I/O bandwidth and raw video consumes **HUMONGOUS** amounts of bandwidth. You definitely want to compress that stuff for things to be fast. Compressed video means less bandwidth required, hence less time to transfer it for a given link speed, hence less latency. So if you want fast video: *Compress that shit!*