# Webcam library for C on Linux using v4l2 : v4l2 official examples

Tags: c++, c, linux, v4l2

I'm trying to write a C program to access to webcam and take some picture then store them,for this reason I'm using v4l2 API.

I downloaded the project, installed it 
When testing the one of the examples given I get the following error

```
v4l2grab.c:329:60: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘V4L_UTILS_VERSION’
const char *argp_program_version = "V4L2 grabber version " V4L_UTILS_VERSION ;
                                                           ^
```

I'm using ubuntu and for compilation I used

```
 gcc v4l2grab.c -lv4l2
```

And to get v4l2, what I did is :

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep libv4l-dev
git clone git://linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git
cd v4l-utils
# Matching the installed version of dpkg -s libv4l-dev
git checkout v4l-utils-1.10.0
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
cd contrib/tests
make
```

For this I followed the explication given by the third answer to this question: [Webcam library for C on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278112/webcam-library-for-c-on-linux)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like there's a missing `#define`, so the string pasting isn't working because `V4L_UTILS_VERSION` isn't expanding to a string literal.

Comment: But I didn't modified anything